# How to deploy React webapp deployed on Docker and GCP only for a set of users

Tags: reactjs, docker, deployment, web-applications, google-cloud-platform

I want to achieve something that Google Play store offers i.e. releasing app to a set of users and the rest of users will keep seeing the existing app.

Is there a way to achieve this with a web app deployed using Docker and GCP?

Comment: It depends what your app is and who you are targeting. Look at chrome web store, GSuite / Google Marketplace options in GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Someone shared an interesting article about Canary build.

> Canary Deployments are where you roll out the new version of your service while keeping the older one alive. Some customers will be routed to the new version while others will be routed to your existing version.

https://stackify.com/canary-deployments/